# jQuery drag and drop with placeholders in fixed grid

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, grid, placeholder

I searched through a lot of scripts but I didn't find what I'm looking for.
I need a drag'n'drop script with a fixed of drop zones, e.g. 5x5 fields.
In this grid the draggables (e.g. 10 item) should be moveable but without sorting and floating. So that a placeholder stays where I took the draggable item from.

Is there a way to realise this?